# Save pod metadata in external log analysis tool

Tags: elasticsearch, kubernetes, logging, prometheus, fluentd

We currently save all Kubernetes logs on a central log analysis tool. We use fluentbit to ship the logs.

Although we are able to retrieve and analyze the logs sent to stdout by the containers, we are unable to find the information shown in pods when we describe them (`kubectl describe pod somepod`). We want to save this information too, as it shows the `Exit Code` and `Reason` for a Terminated pod. Like exit codes 137 and OOMKilled.

Having this information in prometheus would also be valid. In prometheus we can see that [some](https://github.com/kubernetes/kube-state-metrics/blob/master/docs/pod-metrics.md) of the information is present like `kube_pod_container_status_terminated_reason` but the "exit code" is missing.

How could this be performed?

Comment: Please clarify your problem. Do you have problem with OOMKilled or generally with logs? What is your output when you execute `kubectl describe pod somepod`? What exactly do you want to save?

Comment: Hi. The OOMKilled was given as an example. We would like to have in elasticsearch, the information shown when you execute the command "describe" of any given pod. It seems that part of that info is present in prometheus actually, like kube_pod_container_status_terminated_reason, but the "exit code" is missing.

Comment: Could you please show how exactly these logs look now and what is the expected result?